JavaFX not working even after I add the library for it in eclipse
So basically when I add the JavaFX library to the project file, eclipse still gives me errors
I tried redoing it, making sure I had the right thing downloaded, configuring the build path, but none of it worked. Help would be greatly appreciated.


Can you show the module-info.java including the errors in that file? Can you please include the contents of the Problems view in Eclipse?

Did you follow the instructions over at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/? If not, can you try them and see if you can get a project to work?

The error says Module HelloFX not found.  Do you have a module named that?  Or, if you do, is there a problem with that module?  You or others can check by following dan1st's request.

edit module-info.java
module HelloFX {
    requires javafx.graphics;

    exports application;
}

add JavaFX Library
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries
Button New -> User library name: input JavaFX , click Button OK
Button Add External JARs... -> JAR Selection -> select all jars in /home/xxx/javafx-sdk-17.0.11
Button Apply and Close
Project add JavaFX
Project HelloFX -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Tab Libraries ->
Modulepath -> Button Add Library -> User Library -> Button Next
->  Select JavaFX -> Button Finish
